# Como usar o having junto com view em sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ao tentar usar o `HAVING` em uma consulta SQL está retornando o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Mensagem 8121, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 15
> Column 'V_DADOSFUNC.FILIAL' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
> GROUP BY clause.
> ```

Comment: você pode postar toda a query (select, from, group)?

Comment: Você deveria postar a SQL inteira que ocasiona o erro, apesar de ter sido possível estimar uma solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,
Adicione a coluna V_DADOSFUNC.FILIAL em um GROUP BY:

```
GROUP BY V_DADOSFUNC.FILIAL, <<demais colunas>>
```